# How to delete a list of document references using WriteBatch?

Tags: java, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using Firebase Cloud database. I have a collection `employees` that contains documents and each one represents an employee. Each document contains a field `shifts` which is an array of references (of shifts). If user wants to delete the employee profile, it should remove this document and all of the documents that are referenced in the `shifts` array. In order to delete, I use `WriteBatch`:

```
WriteBatch batch = DB.batch();
// ...
batch.delete(DB.collection("employees").document(employeeUniqueID));
```

I'm trying to figure out what would be the best way to remove those shifts. I could fetch the employees document and iterate over each shift in `shifts` and add them into the `delete` list, but does Firebase allows some way to achieve it without iterating?

Answer (score 0):

There are no real alternatives to what you're proposing, unless you have some way of getting the IDs of the other documents without querying the database.  If you don't have them, then you will, in fact, have to query for them, iterate them, and add them individually in the batch to be deleted.